# React material-table filtering

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm trying to implement a custom filter for material table.

The table data is:

```
[
  {
    name: "Tomato",
    color: "red",
    quantity: 12,
    id: "01"
  },
  {
    name: "Banana",
    color: "yellow",
    quantity: 5,
    id: "02"
  },
  {
    name: "Lemon",
    color: "yellow",
    quantity: 20,
    id: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Blueberry",
    color: "blue",
    quantity: 50,
    id: ""
  }
]
```

Columns:

```
[
  {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    filterComponent: props => {
      return (
        <FormControlLabel
          control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
          label="Custom filter"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      );
    }
  },
  { title: "Color", field: "color", filtering: false },
  { title: "Quantity", field: "quantity", filtering: false },
  { title: "Code", field: "code", filtering: false, hidden: true }
]
```

Link to code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-meadow-e3z22?file=/src/App.js:268-751)

The checkbox filter I'm trying to implement has to hide/show all rows that have "id" property of an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

To implement custom filtering, we need to alter data at our end. For that, I did the following changes

> Define state hook for data & checkbox state

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([...testData]);
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
```

> In `control` I called `filterValue` with current action state(`true or false`) of checkbox.

```js
<FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={checked} color="primary" onChange={(e) => filterValue(e.target.checked) }/>}
            label="Custom filter"
            labelPlacement="end"
          />
```

> I filter data based on the condition you mentioned(`id` should not be blank).

```js
 const filterValue = (value) => {
    if(value) {
      const filtered = data.filter(d => d.id.trim().length > 0);
      setData(filtered) // set filter data if checkbox is checked
    } else {
      setData([...testData]) // else set original data i.e testData
    }
    setChecked(value)
 }
```

> In `MaterialTable` I replaced `testData` with `data` here.

```js
 <MaterialTable
     columns={columns}
     data={data}
     options={{
       filtering: true
     }}
 />
```

working example https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-antonelli-gfqcg